# How to visit Kaokoveld, Namibia without driving yourself

Tags: africa, namibia

We'll be in Namibia next month, and would love to visit Kaokoveld, but none of us can drive. Do we have any other options to get there from Windhoek?

Comment: What did I do wrong to deserve a down-vote? Are you not allowed to ask for recommendations of this kind?

Comment: I downvoted. I've retracted my downvote as the question looks much better now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without driving your best bet is probably to do it as part of a tour. The nearest you can fly to is Ondangwa (on Air Namibia from Windhoek). You might find public transportation (busses) to Opuwo, so you probably want to contact tour operators in either of these places and take it from there.

The second option is to find someone who's going there in a 4WD and is willing to take you on. Try travel forums (like those on Couchsurfing) to get in touch.

Comment: You're welcome. Have a good trip!